# Rails join on 2 tables

Tags: activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 tables which are

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user   
   has_many :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :post
end
```

Now I want to retrieve all the comments of a particular user.
I have tried it using find_by_sql like

```
Comment.find_by_sql "SELECT c.* FROM comments c, posts p, users u WHERE c.post_id = p.id and p.user_id = u.id and u.id=6"
```

This works fine. But I want few details from "posts" table along with comments.

Does anyone have idea how to do that?

Comment: Can you clarify: you say you're looking to retrieve all the comments by a particular user, but as you wrote earlier, there is no direct link between a `User` and ` Comment`. In other words, the author information for that comment is lost. Your query ultimately retrieves all of the comments for posts which the user has created, but not necessarily the comments the user has posted. Am I missing something; should there not be a direct connection between `User` and `Comment`?

Comment: You got it right. I just want to retrieve the posts created by the User. I have the connection between User and Comment through Post. I felt that there isn't any need of having a direct relation between User and Comment because in my case User just creates comment for his posts only, he doesn't post them on others posts.

Comment: Gotcha, I understand now. Sorry for the confusion. Check out my answer, see if it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Corrected answer..*

Now that I've properly understood the scenario, a portion of my previous answer still makes sense with one addition:

Alter the `User` model like so:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments, through: :posts
end
```

This type of relationship will perform a join between comments a posts, where the `user_id` of posts is the current user. Quite literally, like you said in the comments, *"the connection between User and Comment [is] **through** Post"*.

Similar to what I said before, the center of the universe in this scenario is the user object. With this addition, to grab all the user's comments would simply be:

```
user.comments
```

If you look at the log, the SQL output is:

```
SELECT `comments`.* FROM `comments` INNER JOIN `posts` ON `comments`.`post_id` = `posts`.`id` WHERE `posts`.`user_id` = 1
```

Which is similar to your original query.

Now that you retrieved the comments for this user, you can simply access the `Post` model data through the `belongs_to :post` relationship, as normal.

In the end, unless you have some special reason for trying to do everything in pure SQL, this approach is more readable, maintainable, and the "Rails way". Plus it saves yourself a lot of hassle and typing.

More information on [`has_many ... through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

Comment: Hi Paul, I believe that there isn't any direct relation between users and comments. It is through posts only.

Comment: @ManinderReddy Oh, I'm terribly sorry, I misread that part. Read too quickly. Let me re-examine the question.

Comment: @ManinderReddy Glad to hear it. Don't forget to "accept" the answer (green checkmark to the left of the answer).